# invisible window that registers mouse events

Tags: python, mouseevent, pyside, invisible

what im looking to do is to essentially set something up so that when a particular key combo is held (for instance <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>) an invisible dialog is shown that covers the entire screen. The trick is I need this dialog to register mouse events - such as move, and click.

I have my mouse events all working and doing what I need on regular widgets, but im struggling to get this to work in the way I want.

The latest thing I had tried was to make a dialog such as this:

```
class MouseArea(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MouseArea, self).__init__()
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        # Note - if you only have one monitor, you may want to turn of windowStaysOnTop when you
        # Disbale the transluscent background, or this will be real hard to close.
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.Tool)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

        screen = QtGui.QApplication.desktop().screenNumber(QtGui.QApplication.desktop().cursor().pos())
        geo = QtGui.QApplication.desktop().screenGeometry(screen)

        self.move(geo.x(), geo.y())
        self.resize(geo.width(), geo.height())

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        # Included so you can see the translucent doesnt allow events to register
        print 'Mouse Moved!'
        return super(MouseArea, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)
```

This will put an invisible window (Tool flag so we dont get a taskbar added for it as well, so its fully invisible) over my screen, once i resize/move it to fit the monitor.
The trouble is that since its transluscent this apparently makes the mouse events pass right through to the widget behind it. With transluscent off, i can get a giant app-background-style colored block over my whole screen that WILL in fact register my events, but now i cant see anything so thats not ideal.

What i want is for this to be "clear" - so visually the same as with the transluscent background attribute, but for it to take all the mouse events. These do not need to pass through to the window behind it either. This window would only be shown when the key combo is held, and in this case the events are not meant for the windows underneath anyway.

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: I understand that you want the window to open after pressing Ctrl + Shift, and you want the window to fill the entire screen and be translucent and be able to monitor the mouse events, am I correct? If so, what part does not work or what is missing?

Comment: The code I posted is as close to working as I can get. The key press to show the window isn't a problem.

What's a problem is that when I make the window translucent so that it's see through, mouse events do not register on it.

Comment: add `self.setMouseTracking(True)`

Comment: Oops forgot the line in the post but I already have that. It just won't track events on a translucent widget.

Comment: @aescript I can't reproduce your issue, in the sense that I can't get a translucent window since in the system I've installed PyQt4 (which is *almost* the same as PySide 1) I don't have a composite window manager that allows transparency. That said, I believe that it *could* be a known (and old) bug: see [Translucent QWidget should be clickable cross-os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945934/translucent-qwidget-should-be-clickable-cross-os) and the [related QTBUG](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-17548). I suppose that it *could* have been resolved on PyQt5/PySide2

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to get this solved by overriding the paint event and drawing a rect with 1% opacity over the area I needed. Working now!